# Facebook Open Graph API - og:metatags being ignored

Tags: facebook, facebook-like, facebook-opengraph

I'm troubleshooting an issue where the page title and image aren't being included on facebook likes. Having hit the OG debugger, it looks like none of the `og:`metatags are being accessed by facebook:

[Here's a link to the debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http://transactivstaging.cloudapp.net:8080/Pages/ProductSummary.aspx?OrganizationProductID=617c54a0-189a-48af-9b5e-002148210208&StoreID=a1d6bc99-9a6a-4e46-bdb4-790be4e59bd4&ProductID=d6748a89-41f4-48aa-a1c1-5c28f87cc47f&FBUserId=100002152993326&PageName=MHMTest&PageID=236549899706529&CurrentPage=0) — it's saying it is inferring the `og:url` and `og:title` properties which are present on the page.

As a matter of testing, I copied the metatags and HTML schema straight from the example on the developer docs and I still get the same warnings.

Here's the HTML and start of the head tag as generated:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:og="http://ogp.me/ns#" xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
<head>
<title>123-ABC Butterfly Fun Carpet 3'10" x 5'5" Rectangle</title>
<meta name="description" content="Transactiv Products" />
<meta name="title" content="Transactiv" />
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="289501899130" />
<meta property="og:site_name" content="Transactiv InRecv" />
<meta property="og:url" content="http://localhost:2609/Pages/ProductSummary.aspx?OrganizationProductID=617c54a0-189a-48af-9b5e-002148210208&StoreID=a1d6bc99-9a6a-4e46-bdb4-790be4e59bd4&ProductID=d6748a89-41f4-48aa-a1c1-5c28f87cc47f&PageName=MHMTest&PageID=236549899706529" />
<meta property="og:title" content="123-ABC Butterfly Fun Carpet 3'10" x 5'5" Rectangle" />
<meta property="og:type" content="website" />
<meta property="og:description" content="" />
<meta property="og:image" content="http://transactivazureprod.blob.core.windows.net/pictureblob/831a4d4a-dbe3-44f5-9ff8-12286cdc33f5" />
```

Any ideas on this?

Answer (score 6):

Facebook reads all properties you can enter your url here:
https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug

Facebook will read the properties you specified, but sometimes will use them **only when all 4 are specfied (and not empty), not only the last 3**.

```
<meta property="og:url" content="YOUR_URL" />
<meta property="og:title" content="YOUR_TITLE" />
<meta property="og:description" content="YOUR_DESCRIPTION" />
<meta property="og:image" content="YOUR_IMAGE" />
```

Answer (score 5):

Obvious flaw. You don't propely end the title. You got `"` in it.

I'd suggest doing a `str_replace('"', "''", $str)` before echo'ing it.

That is,

`<meta property="og:title" content="123-ABC Butterfly Fun Carpet 3'10" x 5'5" Rectangle" />`

to

`<meta property="og:title" content="123-ABC Butterfly Fun Carpet 3'10'' x 5'5'' Rectangle" />`

**EDIT:**

You can also consider doing `htmlentities($str, ENT_QUOTES)`, as suggested by @TwoWholeWorms,

Comment: You're totally right there - something to fix - however, even when I don't have that issue, facebook still ignores the metatags - I also pulled the values straight from the open graph docs example and they give me the same warnings:

Comment: And you're trying with the Linter?

Comment: Yeah - the linter is telling me that it's inferring those "required" properties even though they are on the page

Comment: Good thought - but same problem.

Comment: The crazy thing that I'm not following is that the facebook scraper is missing jsut about everything in my <head> tag. http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/echo?q=http%3A%2F%2Ftransactivstaging.cloudapp.net%3A8080%2FPages%2FProductSummary.aspx%3FOrganizationProductID%3D0f891c3c-c325-443f-a5ab-014acae8b3b1%26StoreID%3Da1d6bc99-9a6a-4e46-bdb4-790be4e59bd4%26ProductID%3Dbbd54c6b-4a18-4a3e-ac33-43fa60d8d7e9%26FBUserId%3D100002152993326%26PageName%3DMHMTest%26PageID%3D236549899706529%26CurrentPage%3D0

Comment: This problem wasn't on the facebook end. An error page was being served up to the facebook crawler as we were requiring authentication to serve this page. Thanks for your help guys :)

Comment: You'd be better off doing htmlentities($str, ENT_QUOTES) rather than str_replace. There's more characters which will break the parser than just ".

Answer (score 1):

Facebook's scraper is seeing an error page when it tries to [visit your site](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/echo?q=http://transactivstaging.cloudapp.net:8080/Pages/ProductSummary.aspx?OrganizationProductID=617c54a0-189a-48af-9b5e-002148210208&StoreID=a1d6bc99-9a6a-4e46-bdb4-790be4e59bd4&ProductID=d6748a89-41f4-48aa-a1c1-5c28f87cc47f&FBUserId=100002152993326&PageName=MHMTest&PageID=236549899706529&CurrentPage=0).

You can access the Facebook scraper's view of your pages through the link 'See exactly what our scraper sees' at the bottom of the debug page.

Also it doesn't just seem to be a scraper related problem as I'm also seeing the same message when I visit the link:  http://transactivstaging.cloudapp.net:8080/Pages/ProductSummary.aspx?OrganizationProductID=617c54a0-189a-48af-9b5e-002148210208&StoreID=a1d6bc99-9a6a-4e46-bdb4-790be4e59bd4&ProductID=d6748a89-41f4-48aa-a1c1-5c28f87cc47f&FBUserId=100002152993326&PageName=MHMTest&PageID=236549899706529&CurrentPage=0

```
ShoppingCart.GetShoppingCartItems.Failed If this Error persists, you can contact our support and provide the following Error Id as a reference
```

Answer (score 0):

I would guess that, as well as the `"` in the title values mentioned by [Robin Castlin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/872719/robin-castlin)  (which you could also escape as `&quot;`), that your `og:url` contains unescaped ampersands.

Does it work if you replace `&` with `&amp;` in that `og:url` field?

So you'd replace

```
<meta property="og:title"
  content="123-ABC Butterfly Fun Carpet 3'10" x 5'5" Rectangle" />
<meta property="og:url"
  content="http://localhost:2609/Pages/ProductSummary.aspx?
  OrganizationProductID= ... &StoreID= ..." />
```

to

```
<meta property="og:title"
   content="123-ABC Butterfly Fun Carpet 3'10&quot; x 5'5&quot; Rectangle" />

<meta property="og:url"
  content="http://localhost:2609/Pages/ProductSummary.aspx?
  OrganizationProductID= ... &amp;StoreID= ..." />
```

to make sure the metadata all contains valid HTML.