# Facebook share button with cakephp

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, cakephp, facebook-javascript-sdk

I'm trying to add a facebook sharebutton that reads the meta tag.

I'm using cakephp and my metatag looks like this :

```
echo  $this->Html->meta(array('property' => 'og:title', 'type' => 'meta', 'content' => 'test'), null, array('inline' => false));
```

When I use the facebook debugger everything is fine, the debuger sends me :

"These are the raw tags that we found :
og:title    test"

Everything looks good.

Now instead of test I want a label coming from a variable :

```
echo  $this->Html->meta(array('property' => 'og:title', 'type' => 'meta', 'content' => $pseudonyme), null, array('inline' => false));
```

But here  the facebook debuger sends me an error :

"Warnings That Should Be Fixed
Inferred Property   The 'og:title' property should be explicitly provided, even if a value can be inferred from other tags."

When I look at the meta tag in my web page it looks good :

```
<meta property="og:title" content="Peter">
```

I have no idea how to solve this :(

Thanks for your help

Comment: if `$pseudonyme === 'test'` is there still a problem?

Comment: if I do $pseudonyme = 'test' just before  echo meta facebook finds the value 'test'

Comment: Could you add the **exact** output of `debug($pseudonyme)` to your question?

Comment: Also, because I didn't understand exactly what you're saying, if you add `$pseudonyme = 'test'` exactly before your echo, is there still a problem?

Comment: @Holt : debug($pseudonyme) returns 'Peter'

Comment: @hakermania : there is no problem if I do   $pseudonyme = 'test' just before the echo. But what I want to do is to use a variable

Comment: Ignore Facebook while debugging: You're adding the metatag in your view template. So what html code is generated when you are using your code snipped with the variable? (Just open the website in your browser > rightclick > source code) As Facebook is giving you the "missing" error, I think the meta tag is probably either not outputted or not valid html. If not, please have a look at the CakePHP error log file and copy the log entry to your post. Maybe it's a simple encoding problem to solve with `htmlspecialchar($pseudonyme)`...

Comment: no my html code looks good it returns 

<meta property="og:title" content="Peter">

Comment: That code is not valid HTML, where is the ending slash to close the tag? `/>`

Comment: it's valid. http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_meta.asp

Comment: In the examples [here](http://ogp.me), [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/best-practices) and [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/webmasters#markup) they always use XHTML with closing tags... Beside that your code seems to be correct - have you searched for [other](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7999984/facebook-open-graph-api-ogmetatags-being-ignored) similar [questions](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=facebook+og+ignored&s=5a7f64f9-bb64-4812-a5d7-fef68ab6b1f8) and tried the solutions suggested there as well?

Answer (score 0):

the problem is that u can't add a undeclared variable to your code....
trying declaring the variable by doing adding `<?= $pseudonyme = '' ?>` line before the 
`echo  $this->Html->meta(array('property' => 'og:title', 'type' => 'meta', 'content' => $pseudonyme), null, array('inline' => false));` 
somewhere in the view template .

Another way it to passing the variable `$pseudonyme` directly to the `set()` method in the related controller.